# How to correctly override and call super-method in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

First, the problem at hand. I am writing a wrapper for a `scikit-learn` class, and am having problems with the right syntax. What I am trying to achieve is an override of the `fit_transform` function, which alters the input only slightly, and then calls its `super`-method with the new parameters:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

class TidfVectorizerWrapper(TfidfVectorizer):
    def __init__(self):
        TfidfVectorizer.__init__(self)  # is this even necessary?

    def fit_transform(self, x, y=None, **fit_params):
        x = [content.split('\t')[0] for content in x]  # filtering the input
        return TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(self, x, y, fit_params)  
                            # this is the critical part, my IDE tells me for
                            # fit_params: 'unexpected arguments'
```

The Program crashes all over the place, starting with a `Multiprocessing exception`, not really telling me anything usefull. How do I correctly do this?

Additional info: The reason why I need to wrap it this way is because I use `sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion` to collect my feature extractors before putting them into a `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`. A consequence of doing it this way is, that I can only feed a single data set across all feature extractors -- but different extractors need different data. My solution was to feed the data in an easily separable format and filtering different parts in different extractors. If there is a better solution to this problem, I'd also be happy to hear it.

Edit 1:
Adding `**` to unpack the dict seems to not change anything: 
[image: Screenshot]

Edit 2:
I just solved the remaining problem -- I needed to remove the constructor overload. Apparently, by trying to call the parent constructor, wishing to have all instance variables initiated correctly, I did the exact opposite. My wrapper had no idea what kind of parameters it can expect. Once I removed the superfluous call, everything worked out perfectly.

Comment: did you try to replace `return TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(self, x, y, fit_params)`  with `return TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(self, x, y, **fit_params)`  ?

Comment: Also depending on the position of `y` in the methods signature it might be required to "name" `y`: `return TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(self, x, y=y, **fit_params)`

Comment: @KlausD. agreed, but fit_params is almost certainly not the right thing to pass in, as it is a dictionary

Comment: I tried both right now, adding `**fit_params` instead changed nothing, exact same IDE warning and runtime exception when trying it anyway. Adding y=y gives a syntax error, because fit_params is entered after a keyword. Changing it around gives another syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forget to unpack `fit_params` which is passed as a `dict` and you want to pass it through as a `keyword arguments` which require unpacking operator `**`.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

class TidfVectorizerWrapper(TfidfVectorizer):

    def fit_transform(self, x, y=None, **fit_params):
        x = [content.split('\t')[0] for content in x]  # filtering the input
        return TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform(self, x, y, **fit_params)
```

one other thing that instaed of calling the `TfidfVectorizer`'s `fit_transform` directly you can call the overloaded version through `super` method

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

class TidfVectorizerWrapper(TfidfVectorizer):

    def fit_transform(self, x, y=None, **fit_params):
        x = [content.split('\t')[0] for content in x]  # filtering the input
        return super(TidfVectorizerWrapper, self).fit_transform(x, y, **fit_params)
```

To understand it check the following example

```
def foo1(**kargs):
    print kargs

def foo2(**kargs):
    foo1(**kargs)
    print 'foo2'

def foo3(**kargs):
    foo1(kargs)
    print 'foo3'

foo1(a=1, b=2)
```

it prints the dictionary `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`

```
foo2(a=1, b=2)
```

prints both dictionary and `foo2`, but

```
foo3(a=1, b=2)
```

raises error as we sent an **positional argument** equal to our dictionary to `foo1`, which does not accept such a thing. We could however do

```
def foo4(**kargs):
    foo1(x=kargs)
    print 'foo4'
```

which works fine, but prints a new dictionary `{'x': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}`

Comment: probably worth to add a word or two about `super()` to answer other questions OP had

Comment: I tried out your suggestion, and I still receive the exact same error. I added a comment in the main post as well.

Comment: I did remove the constructor intentionaly, maybe it should be more underlined